# How do I rename files in sub directories?

Tags: windows, file-io, batch-rename

Is there any way of batch renaming files in sub directories?

For example:

Rename `*.html` to `*.htm` in a folder which has directories and sub directories.

Comment: By batch, do you mean "lot at a time" or in a .bat/.cmd/.sh way? The former isn't a programming question, and on Windows, there are tons of free utilities for that. The latter need more precision, at least which OS you target.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Windows command prompt: (If inside a batch file, change %x to %%x)

```
for /r %x in (*.html) do ren "%x" *.htm
```

This also works for renaming the middle of the files

```
for /r %x in (website*.html) do ren "%x" site*.htm
```

Comment: Notably, this also works for renaming just the middle part of the file. So, if all your files started with website... and ended with .html, and you wanted to rename them to start with site as well as changing the extension, you could do:
`for /r %x in (website*.html) do ren "%x" site*.htm`

Comment: Raven, try putting directories into double quotes. This should fix your problem. Linux escape spaces with backslash to fix that kind of situation and I think Windows has also something of that kind but I can't tell what character for sure.

Comment: I have to Remove .$$$ extension from files simply I write
for /r %x in (*.$$$) do ren "%x" *.

Answer (score 7):

If you have forfiles (it comes with Windows XP and 2003 and newer stuff I think) you can run:

```
forfiles /S /M *.HTM /C "cmd /c ren @file *.HTML"
```

Comment: Here are more examples with forfiles: https://www.windows-commandline.com/rename-file-extensions-bulk/

Answer (score 6):

```
find . -regex ".*html$" | while read line;
 do 
    A=`basename ${line} | sed 's/html$/htm/g'`;
    B=`dirname ${line}`;
    mv ${line} "${B}/${A}";
 done
```

Answer (score 6):

In python

```
import os

target_dir = "."

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(target_dir):
    for file in files:
        filename, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        new_file = filename + ".htm"

        if ext == '.html':
            old_filepath = os.path.join(path, file)
            new_filepath = os.path.join(path, new_file)
            os.rename(old_filepath, new_filepath)
```

Answer (score 5):

In Bash, you could do the following:

```
for x in $(find . -name \*.html); do
  mv $x $(echo "$x" | sed 's/\.html$/.htm/')
done
```

Answer (score 3):

```
In bash use command rename :)

 rename 's/\.htm$/.html/' *.htm

 # or

 find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/.txt$/.xml/'

 #Obs1: Above I use regex \. --> literal '.'  and  $ --> end of line
 #Obs2: Use find -maxdepht 'value' for determine how recursive is
 #Obs3: Use -print0 to avoid 'names spaces asdfa' crash!
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a more elegant way, but here's the first thing that popped in my head:

```
for f in $(find . -type f -name '*.html'); do 
    mv $f $(echo "$f" | sed 's/html$/htm/')
done
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you may use the '[rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename)' command to rename files in batch.

Answer (score 1):

there is pretty powerfull [forfiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles) command:

`forfiles /?`  gives u hint of what is possible with the command.
in this case it can be used like:

```
forfiles /S /M *.html /C "cmd /c rename @file @fname.htm"
```

Answer (score 0):

AWK on Linux.  For the first directory this is your answer... Extrapolate by recursively calling awk on dir_path perhaps by writing another awk which writes this exact awk below... and so on.

```
ls dir_path/. | awk -F"." '{print "mv file_name/"$0" dir_path/"$1".new_extension"}' |csh
```

Answer (score 0):

On Unix, you can use [rnm](https://github.com/neurobin/rnm):

```
rnm -rs '/\.html$/.htm/' -fo -dp -1 *
```

Or

```
rnm -ns '/n/.htm' -ss '\.html$' -fo -dp -1 *
```

Explanation:

1. `-ns` : name string (new name). `/n/` is a name string rule that expands to the filename without the extension.
2. `-ss` : search string (regex). Searches for files with match.
3. `-rs` : replace string of the form `/search_regex/replace_part/modifier`
4. `-fo` : file only mode
5. `-dp` : depth of directory (-1 means unlimited).