# How to rename a string in all file types?

Tags: windows, windows-10

How would I rename a string in all file types not just one file type like `.txt` in Windows 10? Like for example if all my file names were named Bear-(number) but there are lots of different file types like `.html, .php, .pdf, .css, & more` how could I rename them all? I don't want to have to list all the file types in the folder... Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using Notepad++  ? You can do a find and replace in multiple files by wildcard match

Comment: @Jay Notepad++ only renames strings in files not renaming the file itself...

Comment: Just to clarify (because it is hard to deduce from the wording of your question...) Do you mean you want to change a whole bunch of file names with different extensions rather than change a string in a file?

Comment: Use command line then - `rename Bear-{number}.* Bear-{differentNumber}.*`

Comment: @Jay Command Prompt?

Comment: Yes - I'll add an answer, hang on

Comment: @Jay If I use this code how it know the directory/folder??

Answer (score 1):

In windows 10, use command prompt by clicking on the windows button and typing in `cmd`

Switch to the directroy you have your files in - for example if they are in a directory called 'temp' enter `cd temp`.
Another example - if the files are in a nested folder like c:\temp\test - enter `cd c:\temp\test`

If they are on another drive, you will need to change to that drive by specifying the drive letter and then a colon... eg 'e:'

rename all files `rename Bear-00001.* Bear-00002.*`

The * at the end will preserve the file extension while changing the file name itself

hth

Comment: I'll try this hold on

Comment: Just to add some information, if your files have different names, you can do : `rename *.* theNewFilesNames.*`

Comment: Nope didn't work... Got this `The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Can you let me know the filename of one of the files you want to rename and also the command you have typed into command prompt?

Comment: I see the problem. It's cause that's not the name of the file so it says that... I need it to rename all files with this word in it is what I meant. Like for example if there was 100+ files with 83974- in the file name

Comment: Only thing is it didn't rename the files in the sub-folders and didn't rename the folders -_-

Comment: Great, glad to have helped. This command can be made to work for sub-folders, but you need to know a bit about batch scripting for that...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15317773/685341 - it's a bit more advanced, but should work  if you want to go down that route