# rename filenames with index

Tags: python

i want to rename all the files in a folder. Each filename will change from "whateverName.whateverExt" to "namepre+i.whateverExt". e.g. from "xxxxx.jpg" to "namepre1.jpg"

i try the modify code from ([Rename files in sub directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245840/rename-files-in-sub-directories)), but fail...

```
import os

target_dir = "/Users/usename/dirctectory/"

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(target_dir):
    for i in range(len(files)):
        filename, ext = os.path.splitext(files[i])
        newname_pre = 'newname_pre'
        new_file = newname_pre + str(i) + ext

        old_filepath = os.path.join(path, file)
        new_filepath = os.path.join(path, new_file)
        os.rename(old_filepath, new_filepath)
```

Can someone help me?
THX!!!

Comment: Hint: What is `file` in `os.path.join(path, file)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version:

```
import os

target_dir = "/Users/usename/dirctectory/"

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(target_dir):
    for i in range(len(files)):
        filename, ext = os.path.splitext(files[i])
        newname_pre = 'newname_pre'
        new_file = newname_pre + str(i) + ext

        old_filepath = os.path.join(path, files[i]) # here was the problem
        new_filepath = os.path.join(path, new_file)
        os.rename(old_filepath, new_filepath)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you made some mistakes naming some variables, try with this:

```
import os

target_dir = "/Users/usename/dirctectory/"
newname_tmpl = 'newname_pre{0}{1}'

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(target_dir):
    for i, file in enumerate(files):
        filename, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        new_file = newname_tmpl.format(i, ext)
        old_filepath = os.path.join(path, file)
        new_filepath = os.path.join(path, new_file)
        os.rename(old_filepath, new_filepath)
```

Comment: the period should not be put in:
    newname_tmpl = 'newname_pre{0}{1}'

Answer (score 0):

You should probably update this question saying what output you get when you run this. Also, try printing out the value of `new_file` each iteration to see if you're getting a correct filepath. My guess is that this line:

```
new_file = newname_pre + str(i) + ext
```

...should say this:

```
new_file = newname_pre + str(i) + '.' + ext
```

...or, in a slightly more Pythonic syntax:

```
new_file = "%s%i.%s" % (newname_pre, i, ext)
```