# Change files extension in win 7 as batch

Tags: windows

I have around 8000 mp3 files in a folder name music as this:

- music folder/artist1/album1/mp3 files
- music folder/artist1/album2/mp3 files
- . .
- music folder/artist2/album1/mp3 files
- music folder/artist2/album2/mp3 files

please let me know that is there a way that i change all files extensions as batch?

Answer (score 1):

You should do this:

Change Directory (cd) to your folder:

```
cd full_path_of_your_folder
```

then:

```
ren *.mp3 *.ext
```

with `ext` is your prefer extension.
Reference: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rename.mspx?mfr=true

Creating batch is pretty simple like above these commands, learn more at: http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/

For all sub folder:
`for /r %x in (*.mp3) do ren "%x" *.ext`
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/245862/3728901

Comment: thanks,there are lot of folders,do i must rename for each folders one by one?

Comment: It still pretty simple. Use search box, **search** `*.mp3` at the **top folder**, then rename all results.