# Changing file extensions in batch

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to change the file extension of all .rtf-files to .doc in a folder and all subfolders.

I found a great solution here: [Rename files in sub directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245840/rename-files-in-sub-directories/245862#245862)

But my file fails when it encounters long file-names (The syntax of the command is incorrect.)

```
for /r %%X in (*.rtf) do (
ren %%X *.doc
)
```

I am up for totally different solutions as well. Working in a large file-environment that has been changed to Office 365 that does not support rtf - but does support them when renamed to doc.

Comment: get used to enclose all file or path names in doublequotes: `ren "%%X" "*.doc"`

Comment: Wow! How can that be it??? I have googled this for half an hour :-S

Thanks!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the source of the problem was not the length of the file name, but the fact that the file name contains spaces.

Comment: Well it helps to debug your program.  If you knew there was a problem with a specific file you should have seen a syntax error that had nothing to do with the file name being to long.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose in quotes:

```
for /r %%X in (*.rtf) do (
ren "%%X" "*.doc"
)
```